# Deep link action does not work if app is not running in background

Tags: android, deep-linking

```
<activity android:name=".XActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="x.lv" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.x.lv" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="m.x.lv" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

AND

```
public class XActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = getIntent(); [Debugger break-point]
        if (intent == null || intent.getData() == null) {
            finish();
        }

    }
}
```

Well, I do get till the part when my application is start from `deep-link` **if** app is running in the background. If I close my app and then click on `deep-link`, then app opens but I dont hit `onCreate` method with debugger. Why is so? I thought it should work the same even if app is offline/turned off.

Comment: First of all you are calling your deep link application through another application right ? That point of time OS will consider your application as separate process. So it may happen that you close application but in background a **separate** is running. please try **onNewIntent** method instead of **onCreate** at this time.

Comment: I open "gmail" (for instance) and click on deep-link which opens "my application".
`onNewIntent` does not work as well.

Comment: I do get `Finishing task with all activities already finished` even tho debugger dont stop in `onCreate` or `newIntent`. Any ideas? P.S. updated current code.

Comment: Still haven't found a solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Heya. Having same issue ):  Do you have any updates on this topic?